# Returning rows where the WHERE clause was not an exact match

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I apologise in advance for the question title. I really struggled to write something succinct !

I have a table similar to the following:

```
| Item    | Date       | Value |
| A       | 2018-12-01 | 1     |
| B       | 2018-12-01 | 2     |
| C       | 2018-12-01 | 2     |
| A       | 2018-12-02 | 3     |
| B       | 2018-12-02 | 3     |
```

I would like to write a query so that when I give it a particular date, it returns one row for each unique `Item` in the table, and it's `Value` on the given date, **or if it was not observed on the given date, the last time it was observed**.

So with the above table, if I supply `2018-12-01` it will return:

```
| Item    | Date       | Value |
| A       | 2018-12-01 | 1     |
| B       | 2018-12-01 | 2     |
| C       | 2018-12-01 | 2     |
```

but if I supply `2018-12-02` it will return:

```
| Item    | Date       | Value |
| A       | 2018-12-02 | 3     |
| B       | 2018-12-02 | 3     |
| C       | 2018-12-01 | 2     |
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (item) t.*
from t
where date <= $your_date
order by item, date desc;
```

Comment: holy crap. that distinct on feature is powerful.  Talk about obfuscating SQL though...

Comment: didnt know about distinct on. Looks a neat feature. is it only available in postgres

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph . . . It is specific to Postgres (and many Postgres-derived databases).  It is rather powerful,and more efficient than alternatives such as `row_number()`.

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be to query all the rows at or before that date and then use the `rank` window function to take the first one per item:

```
SELECT item, date, value
FROM   (SELECT item, date, value, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY date DESC) AS rk
        FROM   mytable
        WHERE  date <= :param_date) t
WHERE  rk = 1
```